# is there a way to create/replicate directory structure using mtree spec?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I wanted to check if it is possible to create or replicate a directory structure using mtree shell utility?

```sh
mtree -c -p DIR_ROOT > hierarchy.spec
```

The above command lets me save out the directory structure specs in hierarchy.spec

What I now want to achieve is to create this hierarchy back (on a different machine or in a different directory) using the spec file.

```
mtree -u -f hierarchy.spec
```

Using the above command, I can load the spec however, I am not sure how I can create the directories. According to the manual docs, -u should create any missing directories/files which are found in the spec.

I get a bunch of errors in the following format:

```
./assets/051_XF/051_XF_0123/fileasset/crag_input_geo/0016 missing (directory not created: user not specified)
./assets/051_XF/051_XF_0123/fileasset/some_cache_foo missing (directory not created: user not specified)
./assets/051_XF/051_XF_0123/fileasset/some_cache_foo/0001 missing (directory not created: user not specified)
./assets/051_XF/fileasset missing (directory not created: user not specified)
./assets/051_XF/fileasset/crag_input_geo missing (directory not created: user not specified)
./assets/051_XF/fileasset/crag_input_geo/0005 missing (directory not created: user not specified)
```

EDIT:

Following are the few lines from the spec file.

```
#      user: samw
#   machine: atoi
#      tree: /Users/samw/dev/FOO/python/BAR/tests/jobs/TMP_COPY
#      date: Sat Jan 11 01:08:17 2020

# .
/set type=file
.               type=dir

# ./assets
assets          type=dir

# ./assets/051_XF
051_XF          type=dir

# ./assets/051_XF/051_XF_0123
051_XF_0123     type=dir

# ./assets/051_XF/051_XF_0123/fileasset
fileasset       type=dir

# ./assets/051_XF/051_XF_0123/fileasset/crag_input_geo
crag_input_geo  type=dir
    .DS_Store   \
                sha256digest=533b50ac459132a293477e7369bf7cb5592fa428b1afc6d570c349c84b94088a
```

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: maybe you need to specify a user. like ... `mtree -u someuser -f hieratchy.spec`

Comment: nope..I did try that however, that throws invalid option error which is really annoying.

Comment: Can you share first few lines of the spec file ? Hard to provide feedback just based on error message

Comment: sure..edited the question and included few lines from the spec file. thanks!

Comment: Any idea about this? Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: The errors are very explicit about telling you what's wrong -- "user not specified" means you need to add information about which user owns the directory.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the directories, use

```
mtree -c -d > mtree_dirs.txt
```

The created file should also contain something like

```
/set type=dir uid=1111 gid=1111 mode=0755 nlink=1 flags=none
```

somewhere at the top.

Then use

```
mtree -u -f mtree_dirs.txt
```

somewhere else (or on a different system) to recreate the directory structure again.